# Downgrade code to earlier versions of Xcode & Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store-connect, swift2

A few weeks ago I got the latest Xcode 7 beta 5 and learned Swift 2 syntax.  I'd naively thought that by getting the most up-to-date-tools from Apple, that I would be set up the best for app development and release.

Now my app is nearly finished and I want to send it out for beta testing via TestFlight, but got the message from iTunes Connect:

```
 "External testing is not supported for builds that have been created with a beta version of Xcode..."
```

Ok, so I tried switching to Xcode 6.4, but it of course generates a ton of errors from the change in Swift syntax -- which is a pain, but presumably I can learn the old syntax.  More problematically, the linker is complaining about targets specified in XCTests that didn't exist in Xcode 6.4, and I don't know how to fix this issue.

Question is: is there a "handy" way to do this downgrade so I that I can release the app to external testers?

The goal is really to get TestFlight & external testers, so if you have an answer that works while still using XCode 7 Beta 5 (or later) & Swift 2, then I'll take it!

Comment: You can always wait a few days, as next Wednesday is a potential candidate for the release version of iOS 9 (Apple keynote - new iPhone). They tend to release their iOS versions that same day.

Comment: The current version of Swift (1.2) will be obsolete in a matter of days as Xcode 7 leaves the beta state and Swift 2.0 becomes usable for marketable apps, so I suggest you wait a little longer instead of learning old syntax.

Comment: You can testflight with the latest xcode beta. No point in downgrading. Its also a real pain to do so as swift 2.0 has a lot of changes. http://www.macrumors.com/2015/08/05/apple-testflight-app-ios-9-watchos2-support/

Comment: Further to @DavidWong, the latest beta is beta 6.

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess I'll wait. David Wong, despite what that announcement says, in my experience I'm still getting the same message about external testing being disabled -- even now that I'm building the Xcode 7 beta 6 as per JeremyP's comments -- and the email message invitations intended for TestFlight testers still never get sent (or at least never received).   The text for "Submit for Beta App Review" is greyed-out and unselectable.  I'm not using anything else "beta", just Yosemite 10.10.4.

Comment: The other option if you need external testing of the binary is to use a service like Fabric.io however you have to do a bit of cert juggling (like with the old Testflight)